# Tkinter how to lock Text widget by checking checkbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, boolean

I am new to programming and Tkinter. I want to `DISABLED` textbox when checkbox is pressed and open it `NORMAL` when box is not ticked. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def lock_fields():
    if check == True:
        data.configure(state=DISABLED)
    if check == False:
        data.configure(state=NORMAL)

check = BooleanVar()
open_for_edit = Checkbutton(root, text="check the box for editing", variable=check, 
                            onvalue=True, offvalue=False, command=lambda: lock_fields())
open_for_edit.pack()
check = check.get()

data = Text(root)
data.insert(END, "I would like to be able to edit this text only when checkbox is checked.")
data.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It seems that for some reason the check-variable is always `False` when it enters to `lock_fields` function. I tried passing check argument to the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close, only thing is that the `check.get()` line must be in the function. Also you don't need the lambda. Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def lock_fields():
    if check.get():
        data.configure(state=DISABLED)
    else:
        data.configure(state=NORMAL)

check = BooleanVar()
open_for_edit = Checkbutton(root, text="check the box for editing", variable=check, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, command=lock_fields)
open_for_edit.pack()

data = Text(root)
data.insert(END, "I would like to be able to edit this text only when checkbox is checked.")
data.pack()

root.mainloop()
```